# Haskell type-level lambda calculus error (or lack thereof)

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I have been reading the page in the Haskell wiki on [type arithmetic](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_arithmetic) and have had a little trouble with the section on the lambda calculus embedded in the type system. From that section, I gathered that the following code should not work with GHC/GHCi - apparently GHC shouldn't be able to determine the type signature of g.

```
{-# OPTIONS -fglasgow-exts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data X
data App t u
data Lam t

class Subst s t u | s t -> u
instance Subst X u u
instance (Subst s u s', Subst t u t') => Subst (App s t) u (App s' t')
instance Subst (Lam t) u (Lam t)

class Apply s t u | s t -> u
instance (Subst s t u, Eval u u') => Apply (Lam s) t u'

class Eval t u | t -> u
instance Eval X X
instance Eval (Lam t) (Lam t)
instance (Eval s s', Apply s' t u) => Eval (App s t) u

f :: Eval (App (Lam X) X) u => u
f = undefined
g :: Eval (App (Lam (App X X )) (Lam (App X X ))) u => u
g = undefined
```

Note that I had to add FlexibleContexts and UndecidableInstances, since the given code doesn't seem to compile without these extensions. However, when I run this with GHCi (version 8.0.2), I get the following results:

```
*Main> :t f
f :: X
*Main> :t g
g :: u
```

This is especially strange to me, because the type u hasn't been defined anywhere. Is this a result of the two language extensions above interacting with each other and glasgow-exts? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `u` is just a lone type variable -- just like the `a` in `undefined :: a`.

To really boil this down to its bare essentials, consider this alternate file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Loopy a
instance Loopy a => Loopy a

x :: Loopy a => a
x = undefined
```

If you ask for the type of `x` in ghci, it will tell you it has type `a`, with no context. That may seem a bit magical; you simply have to realize that instance resolution in GHC is perfectly well allowed to be recursive, and the implementation goes to great lengths to support this.

We can follow along in detail with what's happening in your example, if you like, but it is very analogous to the above file. Here are the details.

So, we'd like to see if we're allowed to have this instance:

```
Eval (App (Lam (App X X)) (Lam (App X X))) u
```

We know

```
instance (Eval s s', Apply s' t u) => Eval (App s t) u
```

so we're allowed to have it whenever we have both of these:

```
Eval (Lam (App X X)) s'
Apply s' (Lam (App X X)) u
```

The first one is easy, since:

```
instance Eval (Lam t) (Lam t)
```

So we're allowed to have our cake when we have:

```
Apply (Lam (App X X)) (Lam (App X X)) u
```

Since

```
instance (Subst s t u, Eval u u') => Apply (Lam s) t u'
```

to find our cake, we should check under these two rocks:

```
Subst (App X X) (Lam (App X X)) u
Eval u u'
```

From

```
instance (Subst s u s', Subst t u t') => Subst (App s t) u (App s' t')
```

we learn we can have cake when

```
Subst X (Lam (App X X)) s'
Subst X (Lam (App X X)) t'
Eval (App s' t') u'
```

which is easy to make progress on, since:

```
instance Subst X u u
```

Therefore, we can have our original instance whenever:

```
Eval (App (Lam (App X X)) (Lam (App X X))) u'
```

But, hey presto! This is the original instance we were looking for. So in summary we can have our original instance whenever we can have our original instance. So we declare that we can have our original instance, and then we can have our original instance! Isn't that peachy.

Comment: That is certainly interesting. I would have thought that GHC would continue to evaluate the expression, but I suppose not. Is this due to UndecidableInstances, then? Also, when I try to run your alternate file, ghci claims that I need FlexibleInstances and AllowAmbiguousTypes.

Comment: @InThisStyle10s6p What is the "this" in, "Is this due to `UndecidableInstances`, then?"?

Comment: @InThisStyle10s6p re: other extensions, yes, I just fixed up the alternate file. In my hubris, I didn't actually test my assertions, but I've done so now.

Comment: I mean, is this behaviour due to `UndecidableInstances`? I only ask because the type arithmetic page seems to suggest that GHC would fail to compile the example, at least at some point in the past.

Comment: @InThisStyle10s6p Again, what behavior is "this behavior"? (Answering that means saying not just "what happened" but also "what alternative behavior we're comparing to".) I suspect the type arithmetic page is just wrong, because (like me) in their hubris they didn't test their assertions. The fact that GHC does instance resolution in a recursive way has some very surprising consequences (like this one).

Comment: Oh sorry. By "this behaviour" I mean the fact that GHC stops once it has determined that "we can have our original instance whenever we can have our original instance", as you say, instead of continuing to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @InThisStyle10s6p The fact that the question (of whether instance resolution is recursive or not) can even arise depends critically on having `UndecidableInstances` enabled. So I don't think it's fair to say this behavior is "due to" `UndecidableInstances`; without it, it would reject the instances out of hand and we'd never even get to the point where it has to do instance search.

Comment: @InThisStyle10s6p However, for what it's worth, I went and downloaded the oldest GHC I could find, and it does indeed loop when trying to determine the type of `f`. So I was wrong that they were wrong!

Comment: I believe this choice was made to allow for mutual recursion `instance A x => B x ; instance B x => A x` may have their methods to be mutually recursive. This would be impossible if the resolution algorithm looped forever.